# PHP time format, am and pm with periods

Tags: php, date

How could I adjust the php time format to a.m and p.m with the periods included?

```
date('h:i a');
```

Comment: You'd have to do it by hand as a.m. and p.m. aren't supported

Comment: Why don't you just vote to close instead of a bunch of negatives

Comment: Including your attempts in the question is always a good idea.

Comment: Why downvotes? Because you show no effort. SO is not a code-writing service. @Hydra I didn't vote to close because there is a good question in here somewhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do it easy with `str_replace`:

```
str_replace(array('am','pm'),array('a.m','p.m'),date('h:i a'));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

There's no straightforward way.

What I'd do is fetch `date("a")`, see whether it's `am` or `pm`, and then output `a.m` or `p.m` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something that is built-in to PHP. You'll have to do it manually.

It has been an [open request](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50084) for almost four years now.

Comment: This doesn't *answer* the question, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just use str_replace to replace am with a.m. and pm with p.m.